# Android: drawing path over Bitmap is very slow

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, android-canvas

I am developing app which can give user ability to open picture in ImageView  and then draw lines on it and also erase them. But i have one big problem: when i am loading a big image the drawing  process becomes very slow. But when the image is small then drawing process is normal))).

This is an algorithm what i do to draw lines:
1. Open image from SD card (decode image size and rescale it if necessary).
2. Put Bitmap into ImageView by setImageBitmap(bitmap); method
3. Create transparent bitmap with width and height as the original bitmap has (to draw and erase lines on it).
4. Draw or erase lines on transparent bitmap (using Path class) in ImageView onDraw() method

This is my onDraw() method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!mFragmentImage.inDrawMode()) return;
    canvas.save();
    if (mFragmentImage.mShape!=null){
        if (mFragmentImage.mShape.getType() == CustomShape.SHAPE_LINE) {
            mOverlayCanvas.drawPath(mFragmentImage.mShape.getPath(), mFragmentImage.mShape.getPaint());
        }
    }
    if (mOverlay!=null)    canvas.drawBitmap(mOverlay, mMatrix, null);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Can anyone give some advices how to make drawing process faster.

Comment: Did you found a solution?